# Why the progress dialog does not show?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, progressdialog

My coding works where the data is saved in the real-time database. However, the progress dialogue does not work. How to put a coding to show if the data failed to be saved in the real-time database?

```
private void SaveAccountInformation() {

    loadingBar.setTitle("Registration Account");
    loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait while we are registering you in our system.");
    loadingBar.show();
    loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

    String firstname = RegisterFirstName.getText().toString();
    String lastname = RegisterLastName.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(firstname))
        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Enter your first name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(lastname))
        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Last name is required.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    else {
        String userid = databaseUser.push().getKey();
        User user = new User(firstname, lastname);
        databaseUser.child(userid).setValue(user);
        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Registration has been successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent HomeIntent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, home.class);
        HomeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(HomeIntent);
        finish();
    }

    loadingBar.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: I cant share it here, because its too long....

Comment: Where did you initialize the `loadingBar`?

Comment: Inside this Java Class also

Comment: private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

Comment: You show then dismiss the dialog immediately, is that intended behavior that you want?

Comment: Is there a chance of your data is saving too quickly that you are missing the progress dialog?

Comment: Oh no, I want to remove the progress dialog if the data is successfully stored in the database or not.

Comment: progressDialog  only show when you done job in background, and you are working on main thread

Comment: Im not sure @ReazMurshed :'(

Comment: So how should I change the coding @Lokesh?

Comment: please write your db operation in thread simple

Comment: It is showing but your code running fast, when you do any network task then it will be show

Comment: How @Lokesh? I am not clear.

Comment: learn asynctask, thread and use according to your requirement

Comment: @Adda put loadingBar.dismiss() inside registration complete condition before intent

Comment: Still did not show the progress dialog @VishalThakkar :'(

Comment: Can you please check my answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I have understood about your problem you want to track if the data is saved properly or not and show a progress dialog in the meantime. I suppose you are using Firebase database and saving the values under a specific node.

You might consider having a callback function here I suppose while saving the data in your Firebase real-time database.

I am rewriting the code. Please note that the code is not tested and modify if you get any syntax errors.

```
private void SaveAccountInformation() {

    ProgressDialog loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(RegistrationActivity.this);
    loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait while we are registering you in our system.");
    loadingBar.show();
    loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

    String firstname = RegisterFirstName.getText().toString();
    String lastname = RegisterLastName.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(firstname))
        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Enter your first name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(lastname))
        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Last name is required.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    else {

        String userid = databaseUser.push().getKey();
        User user = new User(firstname, lastname);

        databaseUser.child(userid).setValue(user)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Data saved successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Failed to save the data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                }
            }); 

        Intent HomeIntent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, home.class);
        HomeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(HomeIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks sir! I saw the progress dialog but in a few moments, it disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private ProgressDialog  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);

 progressDialog.show();
 progressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
 progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

 progressDialog.dismiss();//close progressDialog
```

Comment: Which type of operations in use progress bar